# Vue - Convert JSON object to a string with specific layout

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, vue.js

I have a JSON object, that is set dynamically. Below is the method `onDragStop` that sets the columns:

```
data() {
 return {
   columns: [],
 }
},

methods: {
   onDragStop: function (index) {
    this.$set(this.columns, index, {
        xAxis: this.left,
        position: ((this.left/SomeWidth) * 100),
    });
 }

}
```

Above will for example create a JSON object like below (for 2 columns):

```
[{"xAxis":329.2921875,"position":"30"},{"xAxis":658.584375,"position":"60"}]
```

Now, I need to pass this JSON object to a backend PHP file, that expects a layout like:

```
"{"1": {"position": "30"}, "2": {"position": "60"}}"
```

The PHP file simply encodes the JSON:

```
$columns = json_encode($request->columns);
```

Now I am trying to convert the JSON string to the desired output, by below method:

```
UpdateColumns: function (columns) {
    this.columns = JSON.stringify(columns)
}
```

However above converts it like:

```
"{"columns":[{"xAxis":340,"position":"30.98"},{"xAxis":658.584375,"position":"60"}]}"
```

I was wondering, is it even possible to convert the JSON object to my desired output? And should this be done in the Vue file - or should I handle this on the backend PHP file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```js
const data =[{"xAxis":329.2921875,"position":"30"},{"xAxis":658.584375,"position":"60"}];
const result = data.map(res=>({position: res.position}))
 .reduce((map, obj, i) => (map[i] = obj, map), {})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good answer... how about `.reduce((map, obj, i) => (map[i+1] = obj, map), {})` to keep things the way OP wants them? Either way, this answer is good.